# 640x360 camera resolution not supported (RealMe and RedMi devices)

Tags: android, android-camera2, webrtc-android

I have been trying to use 640x360 (360p) screen resolution for my WebRTC video streaming. My device(Real Me 5 pro) is not supporting this resolution (got to know from CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP). When I force to create a camera capture session with 640x360 resolution, it worked fine. How to know the list of all the supported resolutions and what are the consequences of forcing a unsupported resolution to create a camera session?